# Integrating Baato Map

Tags: dictionary

I want to integrate baato map API to display the route between the users current location and a specific place but I am having error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
index.html:80 Error fetching directions:

Error:

> Request failed with status code 500
>
> at e.exports (bundle.js:1:7330)
> at e.exports (bundle.js:1:12988)
> at p.onreadystatechange (bundle.js:1:6179)
> (anonymous) @ index.html:80

How can I resolve the error?